# Goodness of fit tests in R

Tags: r, distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I have a population of 663 random balls drawn. The interval of this population's values is `[1,27]`. I want to do a Goodness of fit test to proof if it has a gamma distribution with shape 1 and scale 1.5. Because when I do compute the density function, it looks like this distribution with this parameters.

For this, I used:

```
### VISUALIZATION
p1 <- hist(x, breaks=15, right=FALSE)

### CDF and probabilities
null.probs <- diff(pgamma(p1$breaks, shape=1, scale=1.5))

### Chi test
chisq.test(p1$counts, p=null.probs, rescale.p=TRUE, simulate.p.value=TRUE)
```

I got a Chi-squared really big and a p-value really small, rejecting the gamma distribution hypothesis.

I tried to use F-distribution, instead because it looks like this distribution with parameters `df1 = 6` and `df2 = 20` too. But null hypothesis is rejected as well:

```
null.probs <- diff(pf(p1$breaks, df1=6, df2=20))
```

What is your suggestion?

Comment: This is less a programming question than a question about statistics.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they are all integers. What I am trying to do is to confirm that this population has a X distribution.                                                      If I am wrong, How do I know (and confirm) the distribution of this population.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for the reminder. So, what is the solution to test and confirm this discrete distribution? If you have any source, that would be helpful.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I used `breaks_cdf<-pgeom(p1$breaks,2/39, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)` and proceeded until the test. The null hypothesis is rejected. I tried 2 more tests,  using `ks.test(x, y)` and `CramerVonMisesTwoSamples(x,y)`, and comparing my population against a random-generated geometric distribution. The null hypothesis is rejected as well. For `pgeom`, I am not sure if I used it correctly...I did my best :D.